# Rate limiting an API with a special exception

Tags: api, rest, security

I have a webapp that consumes a REST API. I'd like share the API with the wider world, but before doing so, I need to add rate limiting to prevent abuse / high load from buggy clients. I'd like to make an exception for my own webapp so it has a higher limit.

Is there a reasonable way to do this? Not looking for a 100% bulletproof solution, but maybe something that just makes the API a little more difficult to exploit.

Bear in mind that the webapp is publicly exposed, so I can't just rely on rate limiting by API token, since someone could just use the same token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a webapp cannot hide anything to its users, I don't think there is a way to ensure that the application talking to your API is yours.

Everything you can do is security through obscurity, which is by definition unsecure.

**EDIT**

I would have a solution, still not secure, but that would be an idea.

The first thing is to have two authentication system.

1. Third party authentication (API token)
2. Web app authentication (API token + Web token)

Then it's a bit like your idea. You generate **a token for each HTTP session**. The difference would be that **web app** (calls authenticate as such) would have a **lower limit**. (eg. 10k for 3rd party and 1k for web app).
The reason why you should decrease the number of calls authorized is because a single HTTP session (1 person behind it) should generates less API calls than a third party app. Is it your case?

Of course the third party application could easily authenticate itself as a web app, but then it would have to renew its session more quickly, so you can monitor the number of sessions per IP. *Just be aware that universities and companies are often a lot behind a single IP.*

Comment: Here's a potential solution: when a user initially loads the webapp, the webapp stores a token in the session that expires after some time, e.g. a week. That token is then provided to the javascript, which can then pass it as a query parameter to the API. The API detects if this token matches the session stored value, and if so, increases or removes the rate limit. As far as I can see, it's not perfect, but someone who wants to exploit the API would have to resort to screen scraping.

Comment: This solution is not really secure, because you can easily get a token from a session ID and give it as a query parameter. You just have to analyze how it has been implemented and implement it the same way on your application (third party). See ? But I have an idea, I'll add it to my post ASAP.

Comment: Yeah I realize it's not 100% secure, just looking for some sandbags. I like your idea. Will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Depends. Do you want to limit everyone or the same user? In then first case just keep track of the time when the last call happened and avoid call in the last 10 secs (or as you wish). In the second case you have to check also the user, keeping track also of the session or the token.

Comment: It should be limited on a per-session basis, but some of those sessions might not be authenticated. Seems irrelevant on how to have different rate-limiting tiers though, especially since a lot of API-requesting clients do not persist cookies and thus reset the session on every request.