# Dogfooding our own rate-limited API

Tags: javascript, rest

**Overview:**

My company has developed a rate-limited API. Our goal is twofold:

- A: Create a strong developer ecosystem around our product.
- B: Demonstrate the power of our API by using it to drive our own application.

*Clarification: Why rate-limit at all?*

*We rate limit our API, because we sell it as an addition to our product. Anonymous access to our API has a very low threshold for API calls per hour, whereas our paid customers are permitted upwards of 1000 calls per hour or more.*

**The Problem:**

Our rate-limited API is great for the developer eco-system, but in order for us to dogfood it we can't allow it to be restricted to the same rate-limiting. The front end of our API is all JavaScript, making direct Ajax calls to the API.

So the question is:

> *How do you secure an api so that rate-limiting can be removed where in the process in removing such rate-limiting can't be easily spoofed?*

**Explored Solutions (and why they didn't work)**

1. Verify the referrer against the host header. -- *Flawed because the **referrer** is easily faked.*
2. Use an [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) to create a signature based off the request and a shared secret, then verify the request on the server. -- *Flawed because the secret and algorithm would be easily determined by looking into the front end JavaScript.*
3. Proxy the request and sign the request in the proxy -- *Still flawed, as the proxy itself exposes the API.*

**The Question:**

I am looking to the brilliant minds on Stack Overflow to present alternate solutions. How would you solve this problem?

Comment: You can't.  If your own use of the API that you don't want to be restricted to the rate limiting is just coming from public web pages, then you cannot do anything secure from those public web pages because, as you appear to already know, there are no secrets in public web pages.  So, what you can do in your web pages, so can anyone else.

Comment: Anything coming from outside, could be fake or altered.

Comment: Are you sure you actually have a rate limiting problem to solve in your dogfood use?  Each user using your site and your web pages should appear to be a completely different user to your rate limiting code.  Thus, just make sure each web page lives by the normal rate limiting rules by itself and you should be fine.  Assuming your rate limiting is per client, one user won't have anything to do with any other user.

Comment: Incidentally the referrer is not so easily faked by client-side JavaScript running in a browser. Add-ons and out-of-browser code can though.

Comment: Why don't you consider an API Management solution that provides rate-limiting and throttling on a per-user, per-role/permission or application scope. Eg wso2 api manger

Comment: Why do you think untrusted people will have access to the secret?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rate limiting an API with a special exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074065/rate-limiting-an-api-with-a-special-exception)

Comment: What about lawyering up on them? You can secure your API with a secret key and explicitly state in your license that breaking of this protection will void the free to use clause in infer a major fee. Then you can insert some packet inspection to analyze incoming data with the key and try to find infringements by packet inspection and sue them.

Comment: What stops API "abuser" from requesting fresh no-limit token every expiration period?

Comment: Please don't post solutions in the *question* post. If you feel that your solution is valuable to share, post your own answer.

Comment: How about this: Instead of giving them an API key, tie all requests to an IP address or domain name. Then, have the clients upload a server script to their Web server that forwards all API calls to your server.

Comment: Your dogfooding discovered a significant problem with your public API (which is that the rate limit is too low) and instead of fixing it, you're trying to get around it. Why dogfood if you're going to ignore the problems you find?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Since your own JavaScript client is accessing the API directly, anyone's going to be able to look at what it's doing and mimic it, including use the same API key. You can try to make it more difficult, like by obfuscating your code or putting various hurdles in the way, but you and the person you're trying to restrain have fundamentally the same access. Instead of trying to create a difference in privileges, you'll need to construct a system where it's totally OK that the unofficial client uses all the access in its scope, but the system is arranged in such a way that official use across all clients is greater.

This is often done with per-user access tokens, as opposed to one token for the entire application. Each token's limit should be plenty for typical use of your API, but restrictive for someone trying to abuse it. For example, 100 calls per minute might be more than enough to support typical browsing, but if I want to scrape you, I can't do it effectively on that budget.

There will always be an arms race - I can get around the limit by creating lots of bot user accounts. That, though, is a pretty solved problem if you just add a captcha to your signup flow, at a tiny bit of expense to the real human. When you get into these scenarios, everything's just a tradeoff between convenience and restriction. You'll never find something totally bulletproof, so focus on making it good enough and wait until someone exploits you to learn where the holes were.

Comment: Accepting this as the best answer. The route we have decided to go is to use JWT tokens with a lower expiration and to increase the rate-limit of those calls. We will encode some additional information in the token to let the backend know of the higher rate limit. Since these tokens are signed securely on the backend, there should be no issue with spoofing. Someone could still use the token, but it would expire after a few days and therefor sustaining any kind of bot would be harder to do.

Answer (score 33):

If this is causing you a problem, it will cause your putative ecosystem of developers a problem (e.g. when they try to develop an alternative UI). If you are really eating your own dog food, make the API (and the rate limiting) work for your application. Here are some suggestions:

- Do not rate limit by IP address. Rather, rate limit by something associated with the user, e.g. their user ID. Apply the rate limit at the authentication stage.
- Design your API so that users do not need to call it continuously (e.g. give a list call that returns many results, rather than a repeated call that returns one item each time)
- Design your web app with the same constraints you expect your developer ecosystem to have, i.e. ensure you can design it within reasonable throttling rates.
- Ensure your back end is scalable (horizontally preferably) so you don't need to impose throttling at levels so low it actually causes a problem to a UI.
- Ensure your throttling has the ability to cope with bursts, as well as limiting longer term abuse.
- Ensure your throttling performs sensible actions tailored to the abuse you are seeking to remove. For instance, consider queuing or delaying mild abusers rather than refusing the connection. Most web front ends will only open four simultaneous connections at once. If you delay an attempt to open a fifth you'll only hit the case where they are using a CLI at the same time as the web client (ot two web clients). If you delay the n-th API call without a gap rather than failing it, the end user will see things slow down rather than break. If you combine this with only queuing N API calls at once, you will only hit people who are parallelising large numbers of API calls, which is probably not the behaviour you want - e.g. 100 simultaneous API calls then a gap for an hour is normally far worse than 100 sequential API calls over an hour.

Did this not answer your question? Well, if you really *need* to do what you are asking, rate-limit at the authentication stage and apply a different rate limit based on the group your user fits into. If you are using one set of credentials (used by your devs and QA team), you get a higher rate limit. But you can immediately see why this will inevitably lead you to your ecosystem seeing issues that your dev and QA team do not see.

Answer (score 11):

Buy your product. Become a paid customer of yourself.

"Anonymous access to our API has a very low threshold for API calls per hour, whereas our paid customers are permitted upwards of 1000 calls per hour or more."

This also helps test the system from a customer's perspective.

Comment: The obvious answer. No cheating or faking here!

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, there is no perfect solution to this.

The general approach is typically to provide a *spoofable* way for clients to identify themselves (e.g. an identifier, version, and API key -- for example), for clients to register information about themselves that can be used to limit access (e.g. the client is a server in a given IP address range, so only allow callers in that range; e.g. the client is JavaScript, but delivered only to a specific category of browser, so only allow access to HTTP requests that specify certain user agent strings; etc.), and then to use machine learning/pattern recognition to detect anomalous usage that is likely a spoofed client and then to reject traffic from these spoofed clients (or confirm with clients that these usages are indeed not coming from the legitimate client, replace their spoofable credentials, and then disallow further traffic using the older spoofed credentials).

You can make it slightly more difficult to spoof by using multiple layers of key. For example, you give out a longer-lived credential that lives on a server (and that can only be used in a limited set of IP address ranges) to make an API call that records information about the client (e.g. the user agent) and returns a shorter-lived client-side key that is syndicated in JavaScript for use on the client for client-side API requests. This, too, is imperfect (a spoofer could issue the same server call to get the credential), but it will be more difficult if the returned API key is included in obfuscated (and frequently changing) JavaScript or HTML (which would make it difficult to reliably extract from the response). That also provides a way to more easily detect spoofing; the client-side key is now tied to a particular client (e.g. specific user agent, perhaps even a specific cookie jar) that makes reuse in another client easy to detect and the expiration also limits the duration in which the spoofed key may be reused.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the app in question must be publicly open, you don’t have much choice:

**Pick another way to demonstrate the power of your API.** For example, write such an app and share its source, but don’t actually run that code. Make sure it’s well-documented though, so that anyone can deploy it and see it working (subject to throttling).

The app you run would need to be refactored to avoid client-side API requests and be more server-rendered. You can still dogfood your API, but not in an obvious way—make secure requests to throttle-free API from the server side.

**Adjust rate limitation** to allow for your app to work and invest into performance optimization to handle the load.

And yeah, have the core API throttle-free in the first place, and keep it inside a private network. Throttle in a separate publicly accessible layer.

Answer (score 4):

Can you stand up a separate instance of the UI and throttle-free API, and then restrict access to IP addresses coming from your organisation?

E.g., deploy the whole thing behind your corporate firewall, and attach the application to the same database as the public-facing instance if you need to share data between instances.

Answer (score 4):

You could try to generate a unique session ID, bound to a certain IP address/user and limited time to live. When a user downloads your application frontend JavaScript code inject the generated session ID into the JavaScript source code. The session ID will be attached to every request to your API and the rate-limit is lifted.

The ID cannot be simply copied for spoofing, because it is only valid for a single IP address, user and limited amount of time. So an adversary would have to call your page and filter out the key from your JavaScript source or from intercepting the Ajax request every time a new user wants to use it.

**Another Option:**

Set up a proxy for your own application and use obfuscation. The Ajax requests to the proxy use different names from the real API-calls and the proxy translates them back. So your application would not call `getDocument` on your real API, but it will call `getFELSUFDSKJE` on your proxy. The proxy will translate this call back to getDocument and forward it to actual rate-limited API.

Your actual API will not rate-limit requests by the proxy.

And so that other people don't use your proxy for their own application you change the obfuscation scheme daily. The obfuscated call-names can be generated automatically in you JavaScript source code and configured in the proxy.

A client wishing to use this, would also need to keep up with your changing obfuscation to use your proxy. And you can still use referrer-headers and similar for logging, so you can find people using your proxy. Or catch them when changing the obfuscation scheme.

Answer (score 3):

- Whitelist source IP addresses
- Use a [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network), whitelist VPN members
- Proxy solution or browser addon that adds HTTP headers should be fine if you can secure the proxy and aren't concerned about [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks sniffing the traffic
- Any solution involving secrets can mitigate the impact of leaks by rotating secrets on a daily basis

Comment: These solutions don't apply to a front end web client. Perfect if accessing the API was on the backend.

Comment: @jason they can all be applied to a frontend

Answer (score 2):

Setup multiple accounts, and pick one of them at random at every request, or change which one you use every hour or so. This way you can distribute the load over `n` accounts, giving you up to `n` times higher limits.

Be careful about accidentally shutting yourself down if you are trying to find other users doing this, if it's not allowed for customers.